# Proposition from Mumford's Red Book

Tags: algebraic-geometry, affine-varieties

I want to prove that:

$X$, $Y$ are  irreducible varieties $\Rightarrow$ $dim(X \times Y) = dim(X)+ dim(Y)$.

$dim X$ := max {n | $\exists\quad \emptyset\neq X_0\subset X_1\subset...\subset X_n = X$ sequence of irreducible closed sets}

I found this property in Mumford's Red Book. The author wrote there that the proof it's easy, but I have no idea how to start. I saw a proof on this site, but it involves tensor products and I can't understand it.

Comment: How do you define the product variety without  tensor product?

Comment: @baharampuri It's  the cartesian  product of two sets.

Comment: Ok but what is the variety structure? What is the ideal for the product?

Comment: Can you include your definitions of product and dimension? Algebraic geometry is full of different-looking-and-mostly-equivalent ways of defining things.

Comment: @baharampuri I understand $(X, \mathcal{O}_X), (Y,\mathcal{O}_Y)$ as spaces with functions. I can consider $X\times Y$ as product of spaces with functions. It is useful?

Comment: This can be shown using only topology. Showing $\dim X\times Y\leq \dim X+\dim Y$ is easy, just construct a chain of irreducible closed subsets starting from their counterparts in $X$ and $Y$ (note that you need to show that $X_i\times Y_j$ is irreducible). The converse should follow similarly.

Comment: @user347489 I have to work with Zariski topology.

Comment: @rafa I'm talking about the Zariski topology :)